# Reboot/shutdown server using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm busy building a Web UI that can monitor certain apps on a number of machines via an `RPC API.`

I would like to implement functionality where the user can remotely reboot or shutdown the machine, I figured I would be able to create a 'client' app and expose an API which I can then send a reboot/shutdown command.

But I would like to stick to node.js for everything and create the client app in node.js as well.

Would this be possible using node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a node-ssh client https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2
You can send shutdown -r now through that.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a great module.

Answer (score 2):

`require('child_process').exec('halt -p', console.log)` will execute shutdown locally. Instead of "halt -p" you can use any command you want, including `ssh 1.2.3.4 halt -p` to run that remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on child process, I looked through the entire docs but must have missed that, I've marked the answer above as the answer as it provides more functionality, but I will try this too!